# How do I change a column flag in MySql?

Tags: mysql

Say I had a column that didn't have the Unique constraint, how do I add that constraint?

If this is possible, how do I make sure the elements already in the column adhere to that constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_copy AS SELECT * FROM table; -- creating table copy
TRUNCATE TABLE table; -- truncating table to successfully apply unique index
ALTER TABLE table ADD CONSTRAINT table_fieldname_unique_index UNIQUE (fieldname);  -- adding unique index, replace **fieldname** with real field name
INSERT IGNORE INTO table VALUES (SELECT * FROM table_copy); -- copy data from table copy to original table
```

Answer (score 0):

Add constaint by using

`ALTER TABLE <your table> ADD CONSTRAINT <constraint name> UNIQUE (<your column>)`

Coming to making sure your table adheres to the unique constraint, you can do

`SELECT count(t.<your column>) FROM <your table> t GROUP BY t.<your column>
HAVING COUNT(t.<your column>) > 1`

This query will return 0 for adhering table, >1 otherwise

Answer (score 0):

If you try to add the unique constraint and existing data already is not unique then you will get an error and the add constraint will fail.